# Javascript to split and capture shared path

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture shared path location from an input which has other information to like username and email address. I want to capture all information in an array but I am facing issue on shared path where it has backslash.

Body:

```
Jack,jack@gmail.com,\\testpath\test path\new - path\today,Monday
```

Script:

```
var array = body.split(',');
name = array[0].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
email =array[1].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
path = array[2].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
day = array[3].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

The issue is for the path it adds extra space where ever there is a space
`\testpath\test  path\new  - path\today` .

Comment: You can just use `.split(",")` if you want to split the string by `,`.

Comment: Your're assigning the same value to each of `name`, `email`, `path`, and `day`?

Comment: My mistake I am assigning the value as follows                                     var array = body.split(',');
name = array[0].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
email =array[1].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
path = array[2].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
day = array[3].replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');

Comment: I'll edit your post to reflect that change. You can edit it yourself too instead of posting a comment.

Comment: I don't really understand your question though, there are spaces already in the path in the body and there seem to be the same amount in `path`. Are you trying to replace groups of more than one space with a single space? That would look like this: `replace( / +/g, ' ' )`

Comment: When the spit happens some how for the path it adds extra space where ever it sees a new space. I am trying to extract the path information from the path without any modification from the body.

Comment: Is your body correct? Shouldn't there be '\\' in all places instead of '\', otherwise they'll get escaped?

Comment: `split` does not add space. Maybe you need to check your body string closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = 'Jack,jack@gmail.com,\testpath\test path\new - path\today,Monday';
var b = "name,email,path,day";

        var x = a.split(',');
        var y = b.split(',');
        var array = [];
        for (var z in x)
        {
        var res= y[z] +" : " + x[z];
        array.push(res);      
        }

       console.log(array);
```